# Simple C Programing Round up/down to nearest 0.5

Tags: javascript, c

I need to create simple C programming which look like this

```
1.1 and 1.2 to 1.0
1.3 and 1.4 to 1.5
1.6 and 1.7 to 1.5
1.8 and 1.9 to 2.0
```

This is my example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
 int main()
{
       float i=1.3, j=1.7;
       printf("round of  %f is  %f\n", i, round(i));
       printf("round of  %f is  %f\n", j, round(j));
       return 0;
}
```

The answer for `i` become `1.0` but i am expecting `1.5` and `j` is `2.0` but my expectation is `1.5`
I need a few line to make it happen right?

Answer (score 2):

[for C]

This would do for values greater or equal 0:

```
double to_be_rounded = ...;
double rounded = trunc(2. * to_be_rounded + .5) / 2.;
```

For values less or equal 0 it should be:

```
double to_be_rounded = ...;
double rounded = trunc(2. * to_be_rounded - .5) / 2.;
```

This would do for any:

```
double to_be_rounded = ...;
double rounded = round(2. * to_be_rounded) / 2.;
```

Comment: i got error when copy this. Do i need to modify something?

Comment: You want to replace the three dots by any sane initialisations.